# Using GMP, omit mpz_clear() after mpz_roinit_n()?

Tags: c++, c, gmp

The GMP library provides a big int C API and a C++ API which wraps the C API. Usually you initialize an `mpz_t` struct (C API) by doing

```
mpz_t integ;
mpz_init(integ);
```

(see [5.1 Initialization Functions](https://gmplib.org/manual/Initializing-Integers)). When doing so, you later have to free the memory with `mpz_clear(integ);`. The C++ API's `mpz_class` handles this deallocation automatically for you.

Now, if you want to initialize an `mpz_t` based on existing memory, and you don't want to copy the memory contents, you can use the function `mpz_roinit_n()` ([5.16 Integer Special Functions](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Special-Functions)) for a memory area pointed to by `xp`:

```
mpz_srcptr mpz_roinit_n(mpz_t x, const mp_limb_t *xp, mp_size_t xs)
```

This initializes `x` in a special way so it can be used as a read-only input operand (hence the `ro` in the function name) to other mpz functions. Now, the documentation of `mpz_clear(integ)` says this:

> Free the space occupied by x. Call this function for all mpz_t
> variables when you are done with them.

I wonder if `mpz_t`'s which have been initialized with a call to `mpz_roinit_n()` are an exemption to this rule, because they don't need to be deallocated.

If I'm correct, this would also mean that `mpz_roinit_n()` can't be used with the C++ API's `mpz_class`, not even with `mpz_class.get_mpz_t()`, because `mpz_class`'s destructor always tries to deallocate the underlying `mpz_t`, and this would cause memory issues. Am I correct here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mpz_clear` does nothing on a `mpz_t` set with `mpz_roinit_n`. So you don't need to call it, but it is still safe if it gets called.